# Error when launcihg Docker containter: git source https://github.com/miraks/popen4.git is not yet checked out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, bundler

I apologize for another noob question. The thing is I just study Ruby on Rails as I try to launch the old RoR server (based on version 1.9.3).

I finally managed to 'build' that server using [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/), however upon `docker compose up` command that supposed to launch it, I get this error.

```
[+] Running 2/0
- Container gamerclone-db-1   Created                                                                             0.0s
- Container gamerclone-web-1  Created                                                                             0.0s
Attaching to gamerclone-db-1, gamerclone-web-1
gamerclone-db-1   |
gamerclone-db-1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
gamerclone-db-1   |
gamerclone-db-1   | 2022-09-02 11:47:49.725 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
gamerclone-db-1   | 2022-09-02 11:47:49.742 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
gamerclone-db-1   | 2022-09-02 11:47:49.742 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
gamerclone-db-1   | 2022-09-02 11:47:49.967 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
gamerclone-db-1   | 2022-09-02 11:47:50.296 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-02 09:17:52 UTC
gamerclone-db-1   | 2022-09-02 11:47:50.812 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
gamerclone-web-1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:155:in `allowed_in_path': The git source https://github.com/miraks/popen4.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application (Bundler::GitError)
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:47:in `revision'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:216:in `revision'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:85:in `install_path'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:110:in `expanded_path'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:132:in `load_spec_files'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:189:in `load_spec_files'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:92:in `local_specs'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:159:in `specs'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:518:in `block in converge_locked_specs'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:507:in `each'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:507:in `converge_locked_specs'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:190:in `resolve'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.0/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
gamerclone-web-1  |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
gamerclone-web-1 exited with code 1
```

How am I supposed to launch `bundle install`? If I use `docker compose build` again (as it includes that line), it does nothing.

UPD. In case, you need a content of the Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:1.9.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
WORKDIR /gamerruapp
COPY Gemfile /gamerruapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /gamerruapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

#Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: This isn't a Git issue. Probably not a Docker issue either but you should probably include your Dockerfile here, in case it is.

Comment: Actually, you can just look at the [link to the guide](https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/) - all is there. Dockerfile, Docker-compose. Though just in case I added Dockerfile content to my question.

Comment: You'll need a Ruby expert here (which I'm not): `bundle install` should have taken care of everything, so there's some kind of config knob or something you'll need. Probably it's a version skew thing, where the tutorial is for Ruby 0.2 and you're using Ruby 99.7, or vice versa...